# Can I put fresh grout over grout that was done less than 48 hours ago?

Tags: tile, grout

We had bad light when rinsing last night and today the grout seems uneven in the lines. If I mix grout tonight can I fill in some of the problem areas? Or do I have to dig out all the grout first?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be sure, yes, you have to dig all the grout out first.  Grout bonds mostly to the tiles, less so to itself.  If you dig the grout out, try to do it at a 90 degree angle to the "proper height" grout, this will give you the best adhesion for your patch.  Also, if possible try to make those 90 degree joins where there's more tile to adhere to (avoid starting a new grout line at the corners).

However 48 hours is right on the cusp of where I might try to fill it in.  Typically grout takes a few weeks to fully cure, but is ready to seal after 2 or 3 days.  That says to me that you might still get the new grout to bond to the old.  I know there are cases where a homeowner might accidentally scratch the grout, in general, the tile mechanic doesn't always scrape up all the grout, before fixing something like that.

Keep in mind, if the new grout fails, it will be harder to dig everything out later than now.  The grout is softer now, all the materials are at hand, and there's incentive to finish the job.

Comment: That cure time was really at the root of my question. I hoped there was a chance that it would still bond. We're talking about a handful of spots in a 12 x 20 rm. Thanks for your thoughts Steve.

Comment: @Kate - it's just a few spots I would almost definitely clear those spots out and re-grout.  It's important to note that grout mostly sticks to the tiles, not so much to itself.  If you can get 2/3 of the grout out of the line you should be fine, but with it being pretty fresh I wouldn't think it would be hard to get all the way down.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking now I will gouge out the lines. I was so happy after I got the tiles laid that I don't want to risk it with just a few bad spots. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kate - I'm going to update my answer so it's clear, but you don't have to remove **all** the grout, just the parts where it is low.

Comment: Yup, just at the trouble spots. I understood, it's all good.